# Freemarker template not found

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I'm currently trying to get Freemarker to work with my application using Spring.  No matter what I try I keep getting template not found.  I am not sure if I have the configuration set up properly, but it never finds my template.  Here is my spring bean config:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
</bean>
```

Whenever I try to call getTemplate on the freemaker configuration it always sends back a template not found error.  So if I do

```
configuration.getTemplate("testTemplate.ftl")
```

it always throws an IOException.

I'm not sure if anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: how are you setting the 'configuration' object?

Comment: I'm getting the configuration object from Spring.There is a getConfiguration method from the FreeMarkerConfigurer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `/WEB-INF/freemarker` would only work as a path from within `WebApplicationContext`; otherwise Spring would attempt to resolve it as file system path rather than servlet context path. Is the excerpt you've posted above from the context being loaded by `DispatcherServlet`?

Secondly, is there any reason why are you using `configuration` directly instead of using Spring's `ViewResolver`?

Finally, `IOException` can mean many different things. Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I thought there was some kind of path issue....so I'm trying to use freemarker to help send emails by using templates.  I was originally thinking that the ViewResolver was a little to much.  So I thought it would be better to use the configuration instead...not sure if that is the correct thing to do.  As for the IOException, the message coming back is template not found.

Comment: Oh and I am configuring the bean in the applicationContext.xml file.  I did not put that in the DispatchServlet.

Comment: How is context created for that "applicationContext.xml" (what Spring class is used to create it)? If it does **not** descend from WebApplicationContext, it will **not** be able to get anything from "/WEB-INF" - not unless you specify an absolute filesystem url.

Comment: Thanks ChssPly76.  I'm using the Classpath Application context to load my applicationContext.xml.  How would I load the WebApplicationContext?  Is that the right context to use in a web application?

Comment: It's normally loaded by `DispatcherServlet` (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) but you can create it manually (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/GenericWebApplicationContext.html) and pass servlet context to it.

Comment: Hi @Brock, did you solve your problem in the end? What fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same kind of problem and, at the end, I decide to use the approach below:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileTemplateLoader templateLoader = new FileTemplateLoader(new File(YOUR_BASE_TEMPLATE_DIR));
configuration.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader);
freemarker.template.Template template = configuration.getTemplate(YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME);
template.process(datamodel, writer);
```

Comment: I tried it but did not work for me. I am receiving yet the exception java.io.FileNotFoundException above a existent path. That is really crazy!

Answer (score 0):

you can also set it like

```
    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean freemarkerConfiguration() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean bean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
        bean.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates/");
        return bean;
    }
```

In your case:

```
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
configuration.setClassLoaderForTemplateLoading(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), "/templates");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you must make sure that the file "testTemplate.ftl" is in the folder "/WEB-INF/freemarker/"