# Freemarker Template Not found Exception

Tags: java, maven, classpath, freemarker

I am getting file not found exception for my freemarker template file in  java.
I have searched all links like [Random template not found with Freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987504/random-template-not-found-with-freemarker) and [Freemarker template not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799614/freemarker-template-not-found) , but nothing helped.

I am using ftl file for designing email and this is my code to include that template

```
 Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(GenerateEmail.class, "");
            Template template = cfg.getTemplate("email.ftl");
```

My `email.ftl` file is located in `src/main/java folder`

can anyone help me in this

Comment: the file is not on the classpath at that location or it is not being added to your archive when you build it. That is the gist of the two questions you mention, they are the exact same problem solution. This is a simple issue and there are lots of answers about locating a file on the classpath, if the file is actually on the classpath correctly.

Comment: But i didnt got my answer there thats why posted it

Comment: There is no spoon fed answer, you have to figure out if the file is actually on the classpath yourself we do not have access to your environment. This actually has nothing to do with freemarker, it is a **locating a resource on the classpath issue**. `src/main/java` folder implies you are using maven, your file should be in `src/main/resources` instead. The information you need is in the link to the duplicate.

Comment: The problem is that you are using `""` as the 2nd argument to `setClassForTemplateLoading` instead of `"/"`. `""` is a relative path, thus FreeMarker looks for the template in the package of `GenerateEmail` class.  Note that this is documented in the JavaDoc. (I can't send this as an answer as the question was marked as a duplicate.)

Comment: @jarrod This is a template file that the user may not want to look for on the classpath - it may need to be edited without having to redeploy the application. I agree that the duplicate marking should be revoked.

Comment: so they are deploying an application that has a relative directory to `src/main/java`? that is not what they are implying, **the method call they are using and the path implies the root of classpath**, if they want to look in the filesystem they should use the correct method that looks on the filesystem. *If their intent is different than what they have said they need to clarify their question with more attention to detail and the question will get reopened if the intent changes. That is how the system is designed to work.*

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your `ftl` files in "WEB-INF/email/email.ftl" then access it using `cfg.getTemplate("/email/email.ftl")`.

**Update:** See if this link helps: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/FreeMarker/article.html

Good luck!

Comment: not working for me :(

Comment: are you using spring ? If yes have you configured it ?

Comment: no i am not using spring